# Linux: Identify process causing high *system* cpu usage

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

All the tools seem to either 1) show user/system usage details once you provide them a process id 2) show the stats only for the entire system without any detail per process.

I've checked `top`, `dstat`, `ps`...

Do I really have to script this?

Answer (score 1):

Check `pidstat`; I think that does what you want.

See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349042/get-separate-user-system-etc-cpu-usage-per-process

Comment: Aah ok, I thought you needed to give it a pid. You can indeed run without pid and it displays all processes *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

`htop` can do this. Sort by (and show) `STIME`.